# LightSwitch Copy String to Clipboard

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

I've added System.Windows and Microsoft.LightSwitch.Threading; to get access to the clipboard.

When I run this program I get this error: Invalid cross-thread access.

Any ideas for getting the clipboard to work?

```
        partial void btnCopyFaucets_Execute()
    {
        // Write your code here.
        try
        {
            string CopyText, nManu, nProductCode, nFaucet;
            Faucets cpyfaucet = this.FaucetsSearch.SelectedItem;

            nManu = Convert.ToString(cpyfaucet.Manufacturer);
            nProductCode = Convert.ToString(cpyfaucet.ProductCode);
            nFaucet = Convert.ToString(cpyfaucet.Faucet);

            CopyText = nManu + " " + nProductCode + " " + nFaucet;

            // THIS IS WHERE THE COMPILER IS NOT HAPPY.
            Clipboard.SetText(CopyText);
        }
        catch (Exception damnit)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(damnit.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the Main dispatcher like this:

```
Microsoft.LightSwitch.Threading.Dispatchers.Main.BeginInvoke(() =>
 Clipboard.SetText(CopyText);
});
```

Maybe if it´s a web app you'll have permission issues after that.